# Test-Path with Wildcard Unexpected Result

Tags: powershell

[Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-6#required-parameters) is not behaving as expected.

```
Test-Path -Path 'C:\W*' -PathType 'Container'
# Returns: False
```

I thought this would return true, matching against `C:\Windows`.

When I run the same for `C:\P*` it returns true, having matched `C:\Program Files`, `C:\Program Files (x86)` and `C:\ProgramData`.

I am running PowerShell 5.1 on Win-10, 64-bit.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: `Test-Path -Path 'C:\W*' -PathType Container` returns True on my system

Comment: Thanks @Olaf and others, appreciate you trying on your systems.  I rebooted, and tried again in a `-noprofile` session.  Still returns `$false`.  I'm going to assume this is a bug on my machine, and not PowerShell.  `Resolve-Path` and others work as expected.  Strange.

Comment: Try running in an elevated session

Comment: Are you sure your Windows is installed on the C-drive?